# ValueAnimator.REVERSE create for REVERSE different behavior

Tags: android, animation

I have simple animation that moves the object in Y axis. I want change the behavior for the REVERSE.
    //My Code:

```
ImageView iv = ... //my view
ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(iv, "y", 300);
oa.setDuration(100);   
oa.setRepeatCount(1);
oa.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
oa.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the behavior of the reverse mode. Instead, you will need to create an `AnimatorSet` and play them sequentially.

```
ImageView iv = ... //my view
ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(iv, "y", 300);
oa.setDuration(100);
ObjectAnimator oa2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(/* code here */)
// Add any other code for oa2
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.playSequentially(oa, oa2);
set.start()
```